# How to retrieve an object from a long list having a given (key,value) pair?

Tags: javascript, list, indexing

Hi have a long list of objects like that:

```
var myLongList = [
{id="1", desc:"ahahah"},
{id="2", desc:"ihihih"},
{id="3", desc:"ohohoh"},
...
{id="N", desc:"olala"}
]
```

I need to retrieve the object with `id="14575"`. Since my list is quite long and I have to make a lot of such retrievals, I would prefer not to loop through the list to get my object.

So far, I use a function to index my array from a column:

```
function index(js, indexColumn){
    var out={};
    var o;
    for (var key in js) {
        o = js[key];
        out[o[indexColumn]]=o;
    }
    return out;
}
```

A call to `var myLongListIndexed = index(myLongList, "id");` builds an indexed list and myLongListIndexed["14575"] returns my beloved object.

Is there a more standard way to retrieve objects from lists based on a (key,value) pair?

Comment: Sounds like pretty much the most sensible way to do it, except that it's not a good idea to use `for..in` with arrays. Better to use a regular `for` loop or `js.forEach(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like pretty much the most sensible way to do it, except that it's not a good idea to use `for..in` with arrays. Better to use a regular `for` loop or `js.forEach(...)`.

Like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < js.length; i += 1) {
    o = js[i];
    out[o[indexColumn]]=o;
}
```

or this (requires ES5):

```
js.forEach(function(el) {
    out[el[indexColumn]] = el;
});
```

jQuery version (doesn't require ES5):

```
$.each(js, function() {
    out[this[indexColumn]] = this;
});
```